Creating a server audit specification through SSMS: what is the correlation between Audit Action Type and other columns?
Having gone through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/create-a-server-audit-and-server-audit-specification?view=sql-server-ver15 where it explains how to create an audit in SSMS, I right-clicked Server/Security/Server Audit Specifications node in server explorer, chose New..., and selected an existing audit that does not yet have a specification.
Now, when I select any value from the drop-down under Audit Action Type the window does not allow me to select anything from the drop-down in Object Class or to enter anything in Object Schema or to hit ellipsis under Object Name or Principal Name. Those controls seem to be disabled.
If instead I select anything from a drop-down under Object Class then other columns are still disabled, and I get an error in the top left corner when I hit OK: "Enter audit action type in row N"
The linked article does not mention Object Type column. Regarding other columns, it says that I can enter something in them, but I can't. When I select any value in Object Class and then any value in Audit Action Type then it clears Object Class. Why does this window behave the way I see and not the way it is described in the linked article?
